# How to handle errors on async NodeJS application

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I've been migrating from PHP to NodeJS and I love it. For example, I'm using MySQL and the more queries (async events) I run, code becomes more cluttered:

```
db.execute("SQL query", [params], (err, rows) => {
    if(err) {
        console.log("error happened");
    }
    else {
        db.execute("other query", [params], (err, rows) => {
            if(err) {
                console.log("another error happened");
            }
            else {
                console.log("success");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

With my coding style one query equals 7+ rows of code which I think is way too much. **How do you guys handle this kind of code?** Do you guys use some kind of global "on error" event which fires when any of the queries fails and you just assume in the code that everything has worked prior to this point. I was thinking something like this:

```
function onError() {
    console.log("an error happened");
}

db.execute("SQL query", [params], (onError, rows) => {
    db.execute("other query", [params], (onError, rows) => {
        console.log("success");
    });
});
```

Comment: Promises will help you immensely with error handling because it does complex error propagation for you.  Usually, you will NOT have just one global error handler because every error condition is potentially different in how you need to handle it.  There is no shortcut for good error handling.  You must assess every type of error that can occur at every operation and decide how each type of error should be handled.  Can you just abort the operation when there's an error or are there things that need to be cleaned up (like closing files or databases)?

Comment: My problem is that most of the time there is no fix for the error, client should get "try again" and request should be ignored. In this case error should only happen if and only if there was an unknown mysql error. I don't know how to fix an error where "SELECT 1" fails.

Comment: That's not a problem, that's an analysis of what you should do when there's an error.  If all your error paths have the exact same conclusion and there's never any cleanup to do or extra info to communicate back to the caller, then you can use one common error handling function.  But, you should only do so when you've analyzed all the sorts of errors that can happen in all the places you can get errors and concluded that they all need exactly the same code to run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Promises (look to ES6 Promises or find Bluebird package) are the answer. You just chain them one after another and one of the thing I love - no more "if (error)". You define Catch method, where you catch errors. And one catch is enough for the whole chain of queries.